# Performance testing using JMeter with concurrent users

Tags: concurrency

[image]

I have to do the performance testing in JMeter with concurrent users.Now I am using the synchronous timer and set the rampup time is zero.When i check the report it shows the start time.Milliseconds are varied for all the users.Is it correct or not.If its not correct , what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your screenshot, it appears that you have the synchronizing timer set to 600.  IF that's the case, then yes it is correct.  JMeter will release the threads "at the same time", but it will never be the exact time.

I would recommend monitoring the server side of your application to see how many concurrent users are in the system.